# Issue with Navigate Function in React Router - One Works, the Other Doesn't, Can't Retrieve State

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm currently working with a routing library, and I'm facing an issue with the navigate function. I have two arrow functions that involve navigate, and while the first one works as expected, the second one seems to be causing issues.

```
() => navigate("/some-route", { state: { some: "value" } })
```

```
() => navigate(-1, { state: { from: location } })
```

In the non-working code, I'm trying to navigate back to the previous page using -1 as the argument for navigate, along with additional state information. However, I can't seem to retrieve the state on the destination page.

Answer (score 0):

The function signature for `navigate` when using a delta does not allow for passing any options.

> ```
> declare function useNavigate(): NavigateFunction;
>
> interface NavigateFunction {
>   (to: To, options?: NavigateOptions): void;
>   (delta: number): void; // <-- no options
> }
>
> interface NavigateOptions {
>   replace?: boolean;
>   state?: any;
>   preventScrollReset?: boolean;
>   relative?: RelativeRoutingType;
>   unstable_flushSync?: boolean;
>   unstable_viewTransition?: boolean;
> }
>
> type RelativeRoutingType = "route" | "path";
> ```

If you need to effect a navigation action to navigate *back* to a specific page ***and*** pass some data, you'll need to use the non-delta function signature.

**Example Suggestion:**

From page A, PUSH/REPLACE to the path B and pass the current location along with the other state.

```js
const location = useLocation();

...

() => navigate(
  "/some-route",
  {
    state: {
      some: "value",
      from: location,
    }
  }
);
```

On page B, REPLACE to the passed `state.from` referrer location, or some safe fallback route, e.g. `"/"`.

```js
const location = useLocation();

...

() => navigate(
  location.state?.from ?? "/",
  {
    state: { from: location },
    replace: true,
  }
);
```

Comment: @GuilhermeGSilva Welcome, glad to help. Hopefully this sufficiently answered/addressed your question/issue. Cheers and good luck!